# enviar a mas de dos correos desde laravel

Tags: html, laravel-5, email

estoy desarrollando un modulo de mesa de ayuda en `laravel` y estoy enviando la solicitud desde un correo y quiero que me lo reciba desde dos correos, pero no tengo ni la mas remota idea de como hacerlo, quisiera que me ayudaran con mi problema de antemano muchas gracias, dejo codigo de la vista y controlador

```
         {!!Form::open(['route'=> 'admin.solicitudComercio.store', 'method' => 'POST' ,'files' => true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'])!!}
            @foreach($users as $user)
                @if(Auth::User()->id == $user->id)
                    <fieldset>
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" class="form-control" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                        <div class="row">
                            <input type="hidden" name="moderador" value="{{Auth::User()->nombre_completo}} ">
                            <input type="hidden" name="correo_secundario" value="servicioalcliente@cercafe.com.co">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
                                {!!Form::label('agente', 'Correo a Enviar: ', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                                <select name="agente" id="agente" class="form-control">
                                    <option>direccionmejoramiento@cercafe.com.co</option>
                                    <option>gerenciacomercial@cercafe.com.co</option>
                                    <option>comercial@cercafe.com.co</option>
                                    <option>admincomercial@cercafe.com.co</option>
                                    <option>direccioncomercial@cercafe.com.co</option>
                                    <option>controller@cercafe.com.co</option>
                                    <option>mercadeo@cercafe.com.co</option>
                                    <option>infolomus@cercafe.com.co</option>
                                    <option>coortecnica@cercafe.com.co</option>
                                    <option>puntodeventa@cercafe.com.co</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
                                {!!Form::label('medio','Medio de Llegada:',['class'=>'control-label'])!!}
                                <select name="medio" id="" class="form-control">
                                    <option>seleccione...</option>
                                    <option>WhatsApp</option>
                                    <option>Telefono</option>
                                    <option>Correo</option>
                                    <option>Verbal</option>
                                    <option>Pagina Web</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
                                <label for="">Categoria:</label>
                                <select name="categoria" class="form-control" id="">
                                    <option>seleccione</option>
                                    <option>Hogar</option>
                                    <option>FoodService</option>
                                    <option>Mayoristas</option>
                                    <option>Canales</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            {{-- {!!Form::text('asunto', null, ['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'...','required']) !!} --}}
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
                                {!!Form::label('nombre_completo','Nombre y Apellido del Cliente',['class'=>'control-label'])!!}
                                {!!Form::text('nombre_completo',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Nombre y Apellido','required'])!!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
                                {!!Form::label('cedula','Cedula o Nit del Cliente:',['class'=>'control-label'])!!}
                                {!!Form::text('cedula',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Cedula','required'])!!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
                                {!!Form::label('correo','Correo Electronico del Cliente:',['class'=>'control-label'])!!}
                                {!!Form::email('correo',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Correo Electronico','required'])!!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
                                {!!Form::label('direccion','Dirección del Cliente:',['class'=>'control-label'])!!}
                                {!!Form::text('direccion',null,['class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Dirección','required'])!!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
                                <label class="control-label">Motivo de la Peticion,Queja,Reclamo o Sugerencia:</label>
                                <select id="motivo" name="motivo" class="form-control">
                                    <option>Seleccione...</option>
                                    <option>Calidad del Producto</option>
                                    <option>Empaque</option>
                                    <option>Logistica de Despacho</option>
                                    <option>Atencion Personal</option>
                                    <option>Temperatura del Producto</option>
                                    <option>Falta de Inventario</option>
                                    <option>Tiempo de Entrega</option>
                                    <option>Incumplimiento Ficha Tecnica del Producto</option>
                                    <option>Otro</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
                                {!!Form::label('telefono','Telefono del Cliente:',['class'=>'control-label'])!!}
                                {!!Form::text('telefono',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Telefono','required'])!!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-12" id="adicional">
                                {!!Form::label('adicion','Digite el Otro Motivo:',['class'=>'control-label'])!!}
                                {!!Form::text('adicion',null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-xs-12" id="descripcion">
                                {!!Form::label('descripcion_solicitud', 'Descripción del Cliente: ', ['class'=>'control-label'])!!}
                                {!!Form::textarea('descripcion_solicitud', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => '...' , 'cols' => '10' , 'rows' => '10','required'])!!}
                            </div>  
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-xs-12 checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" title="Debes Aceptar los Terminos y Condiciones" name="" required>Acepto <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Terminos y Condiciones</a></label>
                            </div>  
                            {!!Form::hidden('emisor_id',$user->id)!!}
                            <input type="hidden" name="estado" class="form-control" value="1">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-div">
                                    <label for="file" class="input-label control-label btn">
                                        <span id="label_span">Seleccione Archivo</span>
                                    </label>
                                    {!!Form::file('path',['id'=>'file','multiple'=>'true'])!!}
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                            <input type="hidden" name="fecha_hora" readonly class="form-control">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-7 col-xs-12">
                                <ul class="list-inline pull-left">
                                    <a href="javascript:history.go(-1);" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</a>
                                    {!!Form::submit('Solicitar', array('id' => 'enviar_solicitud','class'=>'btn btn-success'))!!}
                                </ul>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        {!!Form::close()!!}
```

codigo del controlador

```
Mail::send('admin.mesadeayudacomercial.mensaje_solicitud', $request->all(), function($msj)
{
  $msj->from(Input::get("correo"), Input::get("nombre_completo"));
  $msj->to(Input::get("agente"))->subject('Solicitud...Mesa de Ayuda');
});
```

el `from` es para saber desde que correo se envia mientras que el `to` es para quien recibe el correo, pero quiero que me lo reciba dos correos distintos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasar un object de emails y luego con un foreach enviar cuantas veces quieras dicho email

```
foreach($email as $emails){
Mail::send('admin.mesadeayudacomercial.mensaje_solicitud', $request->all(), function($msj)
{
  $msj->from(Input::get("correo"), Input::get("nombre_completo"));
  $msj->to($emails->correo)->subject('Solicitud...Mesa de Ayuda');
});
}
```

la idea es que lo realices mediante un ciclo de repetición.